# Why are spaces encoded when redirecting?

Tags: spring, redirect, urlencode

I am studying Spring's 'Redirect',
It doesn't encode non-English characters, but I don't know why it encodes spaces.

Below is an example.

[When character encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4wge.png)

[When spaces encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfrsj.png)

If you know of any relevant documentation, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

An URL can't contain spaces, so " " isn't valid and must be encoded to %20. That's not related to Spring's redirect, but to HTML standards.